# Pandas: how to find the most common values based on the unique values of a different column

Tags: python

i have a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
0  genre   release_year
1  Action   2023
2  Horror   2020
3  Action   2021
4  Crime    2023


  ...
9999 Action   2023
10000 Thriller   2021
```

and i want it to show the most common genre type for each year

i've tried multiple variations of groupyby and mode but i cannot seem to get it to look like this:

```
release year genre
2023         Action
2022         Crime
2021         Crime
2020         Thriller
...
```

how do i go about this

Answer (score 0):

so you can do it by doing group by as ,

```
df2 = df.groupby('release_year')['genre'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```